# SWI-Prolog program works differently depending on whether I call "make." at the beginning

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I wrote a program in prolog. If I run it like so:

```
>swipl program.pl
?- make.
?- my_predicate(my_arguments).
```

everything works perfectly.

However, if I run it like so:

```
>swipl program.pl
?- my_predicate(my_arguments).
```

It works differently. The predicate is still running, but it loops.

**program.pl** uses `:- dynamic some_predicates/3` and `:- consult(other_file).`. **other_file.pl** uses `:-include(yet_another_file).`. Both **other_file.pl** and **yet_another_file.pl** use `:- use_module(library(tabling)).`.

What does calling `make.` do that makes my program run correctly, and how can I fix it so that simply loading it with swipl is enough?

Comment: This looks like it might be hard to debug without seeing concrete code. Do you have a minimal example you could post? Other than that, you might try running `listing` before/after `make` to see if there are any differences that might give you hints. What if you remove the use of the `tabling` library? What if you manually include the sources of the other files in the main program? Do you use any `initialization` directives in your program?

Comment: `diff listing_before listing_after` is empty. It seems that the difference is indeed `tabling`. If I remove the use of tabling, both runs seem to work exactly the same. I don't use any initialization.